# why does the Xdocument give me a utf16 declaration?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

i'm creating a XDocument like this:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));
```

when i save the document like this (`doc.Save(@"c:\tijd\file2.xml");`) , i get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

which is ok.

but i want to return the content as xml, and i found the following code:

```
 var wr = new StringWriter(); 
            doc.Save(wr); 
            string s = (wr.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
```

this code works, but then the string 's' starts with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>
```

so it changed from utf8 to utf16, and that's not what i want, because now i can't read it in internet explorer.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: There's a Big Red Flag here, the string writer really does contain a utf-16 encoded string.  Even if you override the Encoding property.  How does this get from the StringWriter into IE?

Comment: Good question. I save the string 's' to a file with File.WriteAllText and then open it with IE. Didn't specify that too clearly in my question...

Comment: Right, the File.WriteAllText() call is the one that *really* determines the encoding.  Default is utf-8 unless you use the overload that takes an Encoding.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`StringWriter` advertises itself as using UTF-16. It's easy to fix though:

```
public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding { get { return Encoding.UTF8; } }
}
```

That should be enough in your particular case. A rather more well-rounded implementation would:

- Have constructors matching those in `StringWriter`
- Allow the encoding to be specified in the constructor too

Comment: Ah ok, so the StringWriter makes it UTF-16. I always try to understand the encoding stuff, but it just doesn't seem to stick. Sounds logical that a UTF-16 object like the stringwriter creates a UTF-16 string, but what struck me was that it also changed the declaration in the XML file. Didn't think it was caused by the StringWriter, because i was always struggling with UTF-16 too when i was using the XmlDocument before the XDocument, so i thought it was just a .Net habit or something. So thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Michel: Basically the Save method *asks* the writer what encoding to use, so that it'll use whatever's appropriate. It's a bit of a mess, I agree...

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but for others that use this solution, remember when you new up the object you need to use:

var wr = new Utf8StringWriter ();

Comment: @SDanks: Just using `TextWriter wr = new Utf8StringWriter();` would be fine. It's not clear what you're trying to emphasize - there's nothing particularly odd about this.

Answer (score 3):

Very good answer using inheritance, just remember to override the initializer

```
   public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
    {
        public Utf8StringWriter(StringBuilder sb) : base (sb)
        {
        }
        public override Encoding Encoding { get { return Encoding.UTF8; } }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the `StreamWriter.Encoding` to use UTF-8 instead of Unicode (UTF-16)

Seeing as it's not a StreamWriter this answer is only left for posterity.

Comment: There's no StreamWriter involved here. There's only a StringWriter, and you can't programmatically set the encoding of that - you have to do it via inheritance :(

Comment: Wow yea, I totally misread what was being used. Inheritance it is.