# Microsoft task Scheduler: Task arguments doesn't accept localized strings, and the task fails with File Not Found error

Tags: .net, windows, localization, command, taskscheduler

I created a task in MS Task Scheduler app using simple xml command approach:

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC DAILY /TN "*Hebrew Localized Name Here*" /XML "C:\TEST.xml"
```

This xml has the arguments string (to run a file) with a localized (hebrew/arabic) path name like this:

```
...    
 <Exec>
      <Command>"C:\fold\pythonw.exe"</Command>
      <Arguments>"C:\Hebrew_Localized_folder_here\script.py"</Arguments> 
 </Exec>    
...
```

BUT, finally the file path(Arguments here) added to scheduler ui shows irrelevant characters (like, Ø§Ù† ØªÙ…Ø§Ù… Ø¢Ø²Ø§Ø¯ÛŒÙˆÚº Ø§ÙˆØ± Ø­Ù‚ÙˆÙ‚ Ú©), and the task fails to execute.

[Task Scheduler task's property (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIAJY.png)

Anyone had similar issue!? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It looks like UTF-8 has been decoded as the system ANSI codepage. Does the XML file specify the encoding? e.g. "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>"

Comment: @Eryk Sun: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the xml has the encoding in its declaration '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">'

Comment: Are you certain the file is saved as UTF-16?

Comment: Yes. The xml saved has the encoding for UTF-16. Weird thing is, if I use import option within that TaskScheduler app for this xml, the path looks/works fine.  But, as i stated in my problem, if i use that command , which is what i need, it gives path error.

Comment: If it's a UTF-16 file, then it's probably a problem in schtasks.exe. The example in your question looks like UTF-8 that's been improperly decoded. If I encode it back as 1252 and decode as UTF-8, the result is a phrase in Urdu that translates to English as "all these freedoms and rights".

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  My task xml schema has that UTF-16 encoding ''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> <Task' .. and after editing it i am writing it into a physical path using 'File.WriteAllText'. But, if i use any overloaded parameters (utf8, utf32, ..) with this WriteAllText function the  SCHTASKS.exe command throw error saying "The task XML is malformed". So we have a bottleneck for localization here! :)

Comment: If it's saved as UTF-8, then it should be declared in the XML as `encoding="utf-8"`.

Comment: @Eryk Sun: Thanks a ton for your quick pointers. The question in this related link helped resolving.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248400/why-does-the-xdocument-give-me-a-utf16-declaration

Comment: Okay, you should write an answer with the details that worked for you with schtasks.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference link: [why does the Xdocument give me a utf16 declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248400/why-does-the-xdocument-give-me-a-utf16-declaration)

So using

```
doc.Save(xmlfilePath);
```

instead of 
File.WriteAllText(xmlfilePath, doc.ToString()); 
to save my edited xml helped resolving the localization issue.